0-10V LEDs Indicator
I really liked the solution shared by @Chromatix in this post.

However, that solution works for 14V. I need a similar solution for a case where the voltage ranges between 0-10V, with the following behavior:

L1 turns on when V ~ 2.5V.
L2 turns on (while L1 remains on) when V ~
6V.
L3 turns on (while L1 and L2 remain on) when V ~ 10V.

Could you please help me determine the correct values for D1 and D2 to achieve this behavior? Alternatively, could you explain how to properly calculate them for this use case?
Thank you in advance!

That circuit probably already does that, although the last LED won't reach full brightness until a little more than 10v. You could slightly lower the zener voltage on D2 if you want it to light up at a slightly lower voltage.

I don't think this design from Chromatix is a good one at all. There's nothing to limit base current, those transistors or zener diodes will be toast in short order.

It's furthermore not appropriate to use a shared series resistor for all three LEDs. And, D3 will be exposed to a very large range of currents.

Any suggestions for a good circuit that does what I have in mind?

Without an auxiliary supply the 2.5V LED is a bit difficult to do well- is there such a supply available?

I wouldn't go that route, altogether. You can buy four comparators in a single IC package very cheaply, with open drain or open collector outputs, e.g. the LM339.
Using one of these, and a single voltage reference (e.g. the ubiquitous TL431) is simpler (and probably cheaper) then a bunch of discrete transistors and Zener diodes.
Build three resistive voltage dividers, such that at the desired threshold voltage (2.5 V, 6 V or 10 V) gets divided down to the reference voltage.
Compare the divided voltages with a separate comparator each.
Connect your LED with an appropriate series resistor to the output of the comparator (in a pull-down fashion).

Thank you, reading it, it makes a lot of sense. However, I don't have the skills to create the circuit schematic based on this message. I would be very grateful if you could sketch a draft schematic, even if it needs refining.

Don't have the time, but how about you simply start building that circuit, and ask a question about the circuit in a new question. We're not a free design service, anyways, but we do try to help you get you where you need to be.

The circuit you showed will not work. It has no resistors to limit base current, and something will die eventually. Also, the LEDs should not share a single current-limiting resistor.
Sadly, when you need something to operate down to 2.5V, then you lose a lot of options, and bespoke discrete transistor designs tend to become necessary. In this case, you have to power an LED that wants 1.5V, leaving you with only 1V of headroom. It's difficult.
On top of that, the supply voltage can change. Not only do you need this to work reliably down to 2.5V, but also up to 10V or more. That's even more difficult.
That's not to say you can't use ICs, the problem is finding them, and working within the constraints imposed by such low operating voltages. For example, the two comparators inside an LM393 will operate down to 2V, but with severely limited input voltage range. Perhaps you can find a solution using them. There may be ICs designed for your use-case, but I don't know of one. You may be able to find a rail-to-rail input and output comparator (or even an op-amp) which could work in this application, but I will focus on a discrete transistor approach.
The hardest part about this is making it switch at 2.5V. As far as I know, there are no zener diodes with breakdown voltage low enough for this application, and even if there were, the transition of the LED between off and on would not be very abrupt. The "2.5V threshold" section will probably require two transistors and some peripheral parts:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The voltage \$V_{ON}\$ at which the LED switches on is controlled by R1 and R2, according to:
$$ V_{ON} \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2} \approx 0.6 $$
This simplest way to find appropriate resistances for any given threshold is probably to leave R2 as 10kΩ and rearrange that equation to make R1 the subject:
$$
\begin{aligned}
R_1 &= R_2 \left( \frac{V_{ON}}{0.6} -1 \right) \\ \\
&= 10k\Omega \left( \frac{V_{ON}}{0.6} -1 \right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the values of R1 and R2 shown, this is LED current as I sweep the source voltage \$V_1\$ from 0V to 5V:

As you can see, the LED switches on abruptly at \$V_1 = +2.5V\$. You could repeat this circuit as many times as you like, each with a different R2 to produce a different switching threshold. However, for thresholds exceeding 3.3V or so, you can use a simpler design, made possible by the existence of zener diodes with appropriate breakdown voltages:

simulate this circuit
If D2 has breakdown voltage \$V_B\$, then the switching threshold here is:
$$ V_{ON} \approx V_B + 0.6 $$
Using a 5.1V zener diode, as shown, we would expect switching to occur at 5.7V:

The second hardest problem to solve is apparent in those graphs. LED current continues to rise with \$V_1\$, meaning that LED brightness will not be constant over the entire input voltage range between 2.5V and 10V (or beyond). If that's a problem (it is) then you'll need some kind of constant current sink for each LED:

simulate this circuit

Made with microcap v12, using interactive mode.
Just changed the Zener diodes.
As @Simon Fitch pointed, insert some resistors into the base circuit.
Using the "same" circuit idea, I added some components and modified some.
This circuit uses something as max 15 mA.


XY problem.
Use three LM339 comparators (they come 4 to a package). The threshold voltages can be set by several resistors in series. This will give consistent and predictable 'crisp' thresholds.
The LM339 is very cheap, probably cheaper than your Zeners. Bonus: LM339 is open-collector, perfect for driving an LED.
As it is, if you're using this to monitor a battery state-of-charge, the thresholds will be something like 11, 12.5 and 14V. You won't be able to set things that precisely with Zener diodes. With a comparator this is trivial.

Here's an approach that should work, quad op-amp can be any 1.8V RRIO CMOS op-amp such as MCP6009.
So 2 chips and 3 transistors.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
U1 provides a 1.8V voltage for inputs of about 1.75V up to 24V.
R1/R2 divide the input voltage by 10
R3..R6 provide switching reference voltages of 0.25/0.6/1.0V , corresponding to 2.5/6/10V inputs.
OA4/OA5 compare the two higher voltages and the transistors switch the LEDs. The voltages of 6V+ are high enough that a resistor is sufficient to control the LED current.
OA2 compares the 2.5V, and the output switches a 5mA current sink (OA3 and Q1) with a dropout voltage of less than 150mV. R13 ensures that offset voltage of OA3 does not turn on D1 when it should be off.

To avoid LEDs overcurrents, you must use a "current mirror". Circuit below contains three constant current sources, one for each LED:

LEDs currents can be calculated as voltage between transistors base-emitter (Q5, Q7 or Q9) divided by resistors between base and ground (R16, R10, R13). Considering a standard base-emitter voltage of 0.7 volts, current in each LED will be limited to:
0.7/50 = 14mA
See graph below:

Each zener must have a working voltage 0.7V lower than desired value.
For 2.5V, we should use a 1.8V zener. The closest value in LTSpice is 2.0V, for this reason, in simulation, LED D25 does not reach maximum brightness.

The below is from a very basic project of mine. VCC is 3-5V, but it will work from higher supply voltages with no problem. The LED series resistors have to be adjusted, and the feedback network for the comparators has to be adjusted as well. I leave that as an exercise for the reader :)

Voltage Reference: R1-U1-C3 generate a 1.2V reference voltage for the rest of the circuit.
Battery Status Indicator: A bi-color red/green LED LD1 indicates the supply voltage status. It is green above 3.5V, yellow between 3.0V and 3.5V, and red below 3.0V (the minimum operating voltage for the circuit). When the supply voltage is too low, the measurement results are no longer valid.
Battery Status Comparator: The double comparator U4 (LM393/LM2903) is configured to light the red led below 3.5V, and the green led above 3.0V. Between 3.0V and 3.5V, both colors are on and mix into yellow. R8 and R9 provide hysteresis necessary to prevent oscillations close to the threshold voltage. The divider R2-R3-R4 scales the battery voltage to 1.2V at 3.0V and 3.5V for U4B and U4A respectively.

L1 turns on when V ~ 2.5V.
L2 turns on (while L1 remains on) when V ~ 6V.
L3 turns on (while L1 and L2 remain on) when V ~ 10V.

I've accomplished this with a single red-green LED in the circuit above. It's not exactly per your requirement, but you may find it interesting nevertheless. The circuit costs <$1, and you'd be using a "dime a dozen" TL431 instead of the more expensive LM385. I've used the latter since I have hundreds of them in a bag :)
